# Meaning of $\max(0,x)$ of a set of real numbers of $ f(x)$?

Tags: functions

$\mathbb R \to \mathbb R,\quad f(x) =x2$

$\mathbb R \to \mathbb R,\quad f(x) =\max(0,x)$

I have the above syntax in my text. The symbology in the actual text is a double struck capital R and also a solid small black right arrow.

Could I get some elaboration and or perhaps a link to some text defining what exactly is meant by such a symbology?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f := x \mapsto \max(0,x)$. If $m \le 0$, then $f(m) = 0$, since the 0 in the max will hit. Likewise, $f(-m)=-m$ since the $-m$ in the max will hit.

Comment: yup yup all the same